# Expand paths with tilde (~) in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, directory, path

If I use a disk (not URL) path with `~`, e.g. `~/mike/foo`, then the runtime appends it to the current working directory instead of expanding it.

These don't work:

- `Path.GetFullPath`
- `Path.Combine`

Is there a built-in .NET Core function that would expand such a path safely, cross-platform?

Comment: In what context? Do you want a relative url for creating a link? Or do you want to locate a path in your wwwroot folder?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I should have been more clear - I'm referring to disk paths.

Answer (score 5):

My cross-platform workaround:

```cs
myPath = myPath
  .Replace("~", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile))
  .Replace("//", "/");
```

But there are presumably edge cases (especially cross-platform), as always. So a built-in .NET Core function, if one exists, is preferable.

*(Please add your answer and I'll accept it.)*

Comment: One edge case would be that `/~` does not work in bash as a valid path, but expanded version (using code above) expands into `//home/user` which does